# Regex in Postgres: replacing part of found pattern

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm looking to do some simple partial redaction for addresses. Basically I'd like to replace the street name before the street suffix with ### while keeping the street suffix.

Examples:

`Cherry Street -> ### Street`

`America Lane -> ### Lane`

The full list of suffixes will be known at some point soon, and I could end up replacing the entirety of the address (getting rid of Street and Lane as well as the street name) with something like

`regexp_replace(col1, '(\w) (Street|Lane)', '###', 'g')`

but I can't figure out how to just replace just the word before the street suffix.

Comment: You need to be precise with regular expressions. Do you always want to replace the first part of the string? Is it always a single word? White space is always plain space characters? Does the string always end in 'Street' or 'Lane'?

Comment: Hey Erwin -- only the first part of the string will be removed. The string will not always end in Street or Lane; those were just two address suffixes I chose as examples. I recognize that there are addresses ("Black Cherry Lane", for example) that have two words for the street name, but the request was specifically for one word.

Comment: Yeah, you also asked `to replace the street name before the street suffix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a positive look ahead `(?= )`

try the regex

```
(\w)* (?=Street|Lane)
```

see how the regex works http://regex101.com/r/pS9oV3/2

**Explanation**

`(\w)*` matches anything followed by a space

`(?=Street|Lane)` asserts if the following regex can be matched. successfull if it can be matched

`regexp_replace(col1, '(\w)* (?=Street|Lane)', '###', 'g')`

would produce

```
### Street
### Lane
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The regex101 site you linked is super helpful for me, since I'm quite new to regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL's exact syntax, but you need to reference the capture group you wanna keep. Something like:

```
regexp_replace(col1, '(\w) (Street|Lane)', '### $2', 'g')
```

or

```
regexp_replace(col1, '(\w) (Street|Lane)', '### \2', 'g')
```

Where `$2` or `\2` references the second capture group, so whatever was in the 2nd pair of parentheses will be placed there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- saw nu11p01n73R's answer first and that worked, but in order to learn more I will play around with your format as well.

Comment: Yeah that solution is actually a bit more elegant. If you like regex101, I personally like working with [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) as it visualizes the regex in a flow-chart.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect all street names to be that simple. Therefore:

```
SELECT col1
     , regexp_replace(col1, '.+(?=\m(Street|Lane)\M)', '### ', 'i')
FROM  (
    VALUES
     ('Cherry Street'::text)
   , ('America Lane')
   , ('Weird name Lane')
   , ('Lanex Lane')                 -- 'Lane' included in street name
   , ('Buster-Keaton-Lane')
   , ('White  Space       street')  -- with tab
  ) t(col1);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7bc0e/26)

#### Explain

`.+` ... any string of one or more characters (including white space)
`(?=\m(Street|Lane)\M)` ... that is followed by 'Street' or 'Lane'
- `(?=)` ... positive look-ahead
- `\m\M` ... begin and end of word

The additional parameter `'i'` switches to case-insensitive matching. No point in adding `'g'` (replace "globally"), since only a single replacement should happen.

[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)